# Not working Deployment Adonis.js 5 on iis server

Tags: node.js, iis, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

Exception: E_INVALID_ENV_VALUE: Value for environment variable "PORT" must be numeric, instead received "\.\pipe\220cc144-9315-426f-89af-5ade1dc12879"

at C:\Project\adonis-mail\adonis-mail\server.ts(anonymous):21
16
17  sourceMapSupport.install({ handleUncaughtExceptions: false })
18
19  new Ignitor(__dirname)
20    .httpServer()
21    .start()
22

1 castToNumber
C:\Project\adonis-mail\adonis-mail\build\node_modules@adonisjs\env\build\src\Schema\number.js:20

2 Object.validate [as PORT]
C:\Project\adonis-mail\adonis-mail\build\node_modules@adonisjs\env\build\src\Schema\number.js:33

3 anonymous
C:\Project\adonis-mail\adonis-mail\build\node_modules@adonisjs\env\build\src\Env\index.js:87

4 Env.process
C:\Project\adonis-mail\adonis-mail\build\node_modules@adonisjs\env\build\src\Env\index.js:86

5 Application.loadEnvironmentVariables
C:\Project\adonis-mail\adonis-mail\build\node_modules@adonisjs\application\build\src\Application.js:302

6 Application.setup
C:\Project\adonis-mail\adonis-mail\build\node_modules@adonisjs\application\build\src\Application.js:511

7 HttpServer.wire
C:\Project\adonis-mail\adonis-mail\build\node_modules@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\HttpServer\index.js:48

8 HttpServer.start
C:\Project\adonis-mail\adonis-mail\build\node_modules@adonisjs\core\build\src\Ignitor\HttpServer\index.js:146

Comment: You have updated my answer, I try it in my local, and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

You can download httppPlatformHandler. And change your `web.config` like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httppPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\RunningLog\node.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="E:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" arguments=".\server.js">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
                <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="Production" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

## PREVIOUS

You should copy the .env file under the project path and paste it into the root directory after deployment.

#### Note

Remember to change development -> production.